# O(log 10n) or O(log n) x 10 faster?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Which is faster, running an algorithm with a running time of O(log n) once on an input of size 10n, or to run it ten times on inputs of size n each?

Answer (score 2):

**O(log 10n)** because logarithmic time increases much slower than linear time. You can count it yourslef, e.g.

```
For n = 1000: log n = 10, 10 log n = 100, log 10n = 13
```

Comment: isn't the higher the number the faster? so shouldn't 10 log n be faster?

Comment: @Naomi Say single operation takes time T. Logarithmic complexity means that said operation is executed log n times (based on the input). Because log n raises very slowly it means that with input n=1000 it will execute 10 times so the time taken will be 10T. With input 10n (10 000) it will be executed 13 times so time will be 13T. On the other hand if you did log n (n=1000) 10 times it would need to execute 100 (10 x log n or 10 x 10) times so will take 100T time.

Comment: n=1000
log(n) = log(1,000) = 4
log(10n) = log(10,000) = 5
10log(1,000)=10(4)=40

so log10n would be faster than 10logn because it'll take T=5 and not T=40 right?

Comment: @Naomi Actually no because log n is logharitmic curve and not linear. See here http://bigocheatsheet.com/ Particularly the graph at the bottom of the page. log 1000 is not equivalent to 4 log 10 000 becuase log 1000 is 10 and log 10 000 is 13 so 4 log 10 000 is 52...

Comment: so for example 7n+4 right would be faster than n+5logn right?

Comment: @Naomi I am sorry but I do not understand the question. However in the link the graph shows the difference in what you were asking graphically. The dark red line is log n and it barely leaves x axis. While O (n log n) (same as n O(log n) ) is the purple line that raises rather quickly.

Comment: I mean which grows faster? 7n+4 or n+5logn

Comment: they're both O(n) time complexity but one grows faster so as a rule of thumb, 7n > n so it'll grow faster right?

Comment: @Naomi Yes, the logarithm in the other makes it grow (much) slower reagrdless of the constants. Simply adding n or any other constant does not really affect the complexity of the algorithm and should not really be considered as part of it though. So it is really just 7n (which is linear) vs 5 log n (which is logarithmic) and latter will still be faster.

Comment: So even if it's 7n versus 7n + log n, the latter will be faster?

Comment: @Naomi In that case it would not because you would be comparing one thing with itself plus something extra. Makes not much sense. As I said, constants does not matter, 7n is not a constant. In the original n + 5 log n vs 7n could be rephared as 5 log n vs 6n. 7n vs 7n + log n would be 1 vs log n so obviously 1 is faster than log n... However I suggest to first understand the basic notation instead of creating auxilliary modifiers (constant or not) searching for some breaking point between the two. Or maybe better yet ask the question with the exact algorithms/approaches you consider.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check, you can do limit test.
`lim (log(10n)/log(n)), n->infinity`. ([wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20(log(10n)%2Flog(n)),%20n-%3Einfinity))

if `log(10n)`is 10 times faster then `log(n)`, it should converges to 10.

`log(10n)/log(n) = log_n(10n) = log_n(10) + 1`.
so when n goes to infinity, `log_n(10)` converges to 0. (you can check it by inspect some log graphs)